# Polarity on Current Transformer

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, reverse-polarity

In this [part](https://roboway.in/shop/zmct103e-40-ampere-current-transformer-pcb-mounting/),

[image]

What is the correct way of orientation? In which pin should I give the input signal? Should the current flow from P1 to P2?

Please let me know the correct orientation and how to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Current Transformer. The current transformer is used to measure an AC current. This means there is no polarity as the current changes the direction in every cycle. The mechanical position of the transformer does not matter. The only important factor is that only the wire under measurement must be passed through the hole.

The only thing about the polarity is that when the current is from P1 to P2, then the current in the secondary is from 1 to 2.

To use it, you need to put the wire that you want to measure the current through the hole of the core. This will be your primary coil (single wire, indicated as P1 and P2 in the image). Then, read the RMS current of the secondary (from pin 1 to 2). The data specifies that the ratio is 2000 to 1. It also gives an example of passing 5A, which will lead to 25mA on secondary. You might use a small resistor to convert this to a voltage to read it with ADC input.

This Current Transformer has a closed core. However, there are versions that the core opens up for simpler placement of measuring current through the [core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_transformer).
[image: CT]

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification. So, since I am planning to measure AC current, I do not need to take care about the orientation of the CT as well as the Pins 1 and 2 of the secondary, right? I can connect in whichever way I want as it would not make any difference as I am measuring AC current which changes direction, correct?

Comment: Exactly. Put the measuring wire through the hole and measure the RMS current from the output terminals (1 and 2). There is no polarity to worry about. If you are using a microcontroller or any ADC input that needs a DC voltage, you need to convert it to voltage (by using a resistor or a Hall current sensor), rectify it and then do the measurement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and clarification. I have accepted your answer. Just a final follow-up: Does this CT work with only AC currents, or we can use for DC as well? If we use for DC, we need to take care about the orientation as you said, right? One of the final sub-question is, if I connect this CT on earth line, does the orientation matter? Because, I am not sure, in AC lines, does AC current flow on earth in case of fault?

Comment: No, unfortunately, it's a transformer, and they can only transfer energy through the changing magnetic field. So, it can not be used for DC current. If you need an isolated DC current sensor, you can use ACSxxx series like ACS712 up to 30A and ACS758 up to 100A. Some of these even can be used for AC current. Check the datasheet to make sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification